# How to get values for certain keys from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

My Input JSON data:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "config": "current",
            "id": "0"
        },
        {
            "config": "current",
            "id": "1"
        },
        {
            "config": "current",
            "id": "2"
        },
        {
            "config": "current",
            "id": "3"
        },
        {
            "config": "previous",
            "id": "4",
        },
        {
            "config": "previous",
            "id": "5"
        },
        {
            "config": "current",
            "id": "6"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to form a dictionary of lists out of above input data based on common key/value pair:

```
{
    "current": ["0", "1", "2", "3", "6"],
    "previous": ["4", "5"]
}
```

How can this be achieved using python?

Comment: This is actually an invalid JSON, `"id": "4",` should be `"id": "4"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already know [how to parse JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7771011/4518341), you can do this:

```
d = {
    "data": [
        {"config": "current", "id": "0"},
        {"config": "current", "id": "1"},
        {"config": "current", "id": "2"},
        {"config": "current", "id": "3"},
        {"config": "previous", "id": "4"},
        {"config": "previous", "id": "5"},
        {"config": "current", "id": "6"}]
    }

result = {}
for d0 in d['data']:
    ids = result.setdefault(d0['config'], [])
    ids.append(d0['id'])

print(result)
# -> {'current': ['0', '1', '2', '3', '6'], 'previous': ['4', '5']}
```

- [`dict.setdefault()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7771011/4518341) is used to get the id list if it exists, or if not, set it to a default, which is an empty list here. It's functionally the same as this:

  ```
  config = d0['config']
  if config not in result:
      result[config] = []
  result[config].append(d0['id'])
  ```

  You could also use [`collections.defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to do the same thing even more easily.

  *[This explanation is taken from [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65587884/4518341).]*

Comment: Thank you so much @wjandrea. I was trying to do it in a much complex way. Using dict.setdefault() is much easier which i was not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

```
jsn = {
    "data": [
        {"config": "current", "id": "0"},
        {"config": "current", "id": "1"},
        {"config": "current", "id": "2"},
        {"config": "current", "id": "3"},
        {"config": "previous", "id": "4",},
        {"config": "previous", "id": "5"},
        {"config": "current", "id": "6"}
    ]
}

current = [x["id"] for x in jsn["data"] if x["config"] == "current"]
previous = [x["id"] for x in jsn["data"] if x["config"] == "previous"]

res = {"current": current, "previous": previous}

print(res) # {'current': ['0', '1', '2', '3', '6'], 'previous': ['4', '5']}
```

Or the same algorigthm with a function:

```
def get_ids(json_string, key):
    return [x["id"] for x in json_string["data"] if x["config"] == key]

res = { 
    "current": get_ids(jsn, "current"), 
    "previous": get_ids(jsn, "previous") 
    }

print(res) # {'current': ['0', '1', '2', '3', '6'], 'previous': ['4', '5']}
```

Comment: You might want to avoid calling it `json` cause that's the name of the [stdlib JSON library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Comment: Ok. Renamed it to `jsn`